# Sum of elements of subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, divisibility

Given $n$ and $k$, find the number of non-empty subsets of $\left\{1^1,2^2,3^3,...,n^n\right\}$, the sum of whose elements is divisible by $k$.

$n$ can be any integer from $1$ to $10^{400}$, and
$k$ can be any integer from $3$ to $50$.

Comment: might help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27258     https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3357056

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.